# BindSelect2 is not working for select box

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

Hi i have a problem about `BindSelect2`. i get my value(`Variables.id`) and i get `id` and i see it is "2" but i can not bind to `"#selectType"`. i am already bind my the other project like this but this is not working i don't understand where is my problem.

my code is :

```
Core.BindSelect2("#selectType", Variables.id);
```

Core.BindSelect2 is

```
BindSelect2: function (objectAttr, value) {
         $(objectAttr).val(value).change();
    },
```

Comment: Try change `$(objectAttr).val(value).change();` for `$(objectAttr).val(value).trigger('change');`

Comment: it is not worked sir